# sitecollection is not opening giving page not found error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

while accessing sharepoint sitecollection in localhost showing page not found error.If we create new sitecollection it works.please help me.

Comment: give us more details about the issue, Old site collection is not accessible? are you accessing on the Server or from client computer?

Answer (score 0):

Debug the issue with event viewer and sharepoint log files.

Browse the site and pen log file to view the error or use LogViewer.

This type of issue is mainly because error in wsp